# Error while run reindex "405 Method Not Allowed"

Tags: reindex, magento2.4.3

I have one major error in reindex magento 2, i have try all things about Elasticsearch and I have find solution for that last one week but I didn't get any solution for that anyone help me into that.

When i have run indexer:reindex CMD give me this error

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:17
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method GET is not allowed for this URL.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 405 Method Not Allowed
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Actually issue is that before sometime I have import product through BigBuy_MgMipConnector and after that process this issue happen.

after the import process in adminside product page not open - https://prnt.sc/vWlVvQkTQAJU
and in frontend no product show into the category page - https://prnt.sc/VUP-GM9wpD_L

Please help me into that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command it works, hit the below-provided commands

**  server-side index disk issue when indexes are stuck.

curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'

curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you check any third-party extension install for product import related.and after that you check elastic -search enable or disable on sever side. Then apply two commands below and after apply reindex commands. I hope slove this issue.

**Indexing** **command**

curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'

curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'